# How can i pass different props to more than one children component from the parent one in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, web, components

Im working on a color palette generator in React, and the problem i have is that when i try to pass different colors to every one of the child divs that will form the color palette every one gets the same color.

Here is the code

```
    class ColorPaletteContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      color: null,
    };
    this.setRandomColor = this.setRandomColor.bind(this);
  }

  setRandomColor() {
    let randomColor = "rgb(";
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      randomColor += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      if (i < 2) {
        randomColor += ",";
      }
    }
    randomColor += ")";
    this.setState({
      color: randomColor,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ColorDiv color={this.state.color}></ColorDiv>
        <ColorDiv color={this.state.color}></ColorDiv>
        <ColorDiv color={this.state.color}></ColorDiv>
        <button onClick={this.setRandomColor}>Press me!</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}

class ColorDiv extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 style={{ background: this.props.color }}>This is a color div!</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Basically the parent component passes the same color to all the 3 child components, because im passing the same state. Any idea of how i can pass different colors?

Answer (score 0):

Make your state an array of colors like

```
this.state = {
  colors: [],
}
```

Then generate and push `n` randoms colors into it, iterate over the array and render the children

It will look something like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      colors: []
    };
    this.setRandomColors = this.setRandomColors.bind(this);
  }

  generateRandomColor() {
    let randomColor = "rgb(";
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      randomColor += Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
      if (i < 2) {
        randomColor += ",";
      }
    }
    randomColor += ")";
    return randomColor;
  }
  setRandomColors() {
    const colors = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      colors.push(this.generateRandomColor());
    }
    this.setState(() => { return {colors: colors}; });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.colors.map((color) => {
          return <ColorDiv color={color}></ColorDiv>;
        })}
        <button onClick={this.setRandomColors}>Press me!</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That is a gretat  solution but in order to do that i need to know how many child components are going to be rendered, my ideal solution would be one that no matter how many color divs i put i always generate a random color for every one.

Comment: In your question you have 3 hardcoded children. *"parent component passes the same color to all the 3 child components"* this was your problem statement. Where does number of children come from?

Comment: @Gabri here is a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-cartwright-07pgi?file=/src/App.js:0-1005